# How to manipulate the style of an ionic component via angular code

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, styles

Can anyone tell me what is the best practise to manipulate the style of an ionic v4 component only via angular code?

For example, the best practise to change only via angular code the background color of a ionic button after that it is clicked.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Change Ionic's CSS varibles

The easiest way is to do it via CSS variables.

Example to change a button:

```html
<ion-button class="my-button">
    Click me
</ion-button>
```

```css
.my-button {
  --background: blue;
  --color: red;
  --border-radius: 10%;
}
```

This would result into a button with a blue background, red text color and a border radious of 10%.

You can find the available CSS variables for each component in the docs:
[Button CSS Custom Properties](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/button#css-custom-properties)

Or for example for `ion-item`: [Item CSS Custom Properties](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/item#css-custom-properties)

I hope this helps!

## Dynamic CSS classes

TS Compoment:

```
export class AppComponent {

  isActive = true;

  constructor(
  ) { 
  }

  toggleActive() {
    this.isActive = !this.isActive;
  }
}
```

HTML template:

```html
<ion-button [class.active]='isActive' (click)='toggleActive()'>
   Click to toggle color!
</ion-button>
```

CSS Style:

```css
.active {
  --background: green;
}
```

For more powerful options refer to the [NgClass Angular documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) pleaser

Comment: Thank you for your help!
But I need to set the style via angular code, not via ccs. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Why would you like to do that? Styling things explicit via TypeScript isn't recommended. You should stick to the CSS code, especially with the CSS-variables. That's a lot more powerful, more performant and mightier.

Comment: Because I need to update the style of some ionic components after that some events happen (for example after the click of a button, or after a timeout, ecc.).
How I can do this via angular-css code?

Comment: Thank you very much!
This is nearly what I need. 
I'll ask you another question: I have generated some ion-buttons in the html code using the *ngfor directive and I need to assign the [class.active] (as you have shown to me) only to one of these ion-buttons. How can I assign the [class.active] only at that ion-button that satisfies a particular condition and not to others?

Comment: [class.active]='isActive' --> the 'isActive' is just an expression. So you would just have to mention a function instead of the boolean variable and pass the value generated by your *ngFor directive. The function evaluates your particular condition returning true or false. 
Please, don't forget to mark the answer as correct.

Comment: Thank you very much! That's exactly what I needed